# pass variables from .ts to .html in ionic and angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, fetch, ionic4

I am new to ionic 4 and angular and retrieving json data from http, in console I got the json perfectly, how can I pass this data from .ts to .html and show them like for each

[image]

**home.page.ts**

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://mysite/reset-api.php').subscribe((response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
});
  }
}
```

**home.page.html**

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-subtitle>  Title   </ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-title>Card Title</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
  
    <ion-card-content>
      Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in awhile,
      and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
    




</ion-content>
```

Comment: This is angular 101. Why not start with the angular tutorial (tour of heroes), that will cover this topic right off the bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your response from the API in a local variable in the TS file.  It looks like your JSON response is an array.  Each item appears to have an `id` and a `title`, although presumably each element of the array has other fields, too.

You can use an `*ngFor*` to iterate over that variable from the TS file in your HTML template.  And then in each loop, access fields of those array elements by name.  For example, `{{ item.title }}` in the template would be replaced by the value of `title` for that array element.

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  dataArray;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://mysite/reset-api.php').subscribe((response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.dataArray = response;
});
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of dataArray">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{ item.title }}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-title>Card Title</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
  
    <ion-card-content>
      Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in awhile,
      and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
    




</ion-content>
```

Comment: as clear as the sun, thnx

Answer (score 0):

thanks all, can I ask more please regarding the same, I added a clickable button to show another page that has more info about the selected item,

```html
    <ion-list *ngFor="let item of dataArray">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://mysite//uploads/{{ item.document }}">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <ion-label>
        <h2 color="primary">{{ item.title }}</h2>
        <h3>{{ item.city }}</h3>
        </ion-label>
        <ion-button color="primary"  item-end>Show</ion-button>
      
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

I tried to open another page but I filed, how can I open another page>